# Flutter App does not start when boot-completed

Tags: android, flutter, intellij-idea, app-startup

I followed the guide provided on this StackOverflow [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265601/how-to-start-flutter-app-as-a-background-service-on-system-startup), yet every time I build my app, I keep getting this error message

please what am I doing wrong?

> Launching lib/main.dart on TECNO KF7j in debug mode... Running Gradle
> task 'assembleDebug'... Realm binaries for realm@1.4.0 already
> downloaded Realm install command finished. ✓  Built
> build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk. Installing
> build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk...
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266): Process: com.example.fineapp, PID:
> 27266 E/AndroidRuntime(27266): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
> start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.fineapp/com.example.fineapp.MainActivity}:
> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
> Intent { act=android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION
> dat=com.example.fineapp:com.example.fineapp }
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3634)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3879)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2203)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:268)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8017)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> Method) E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:627)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:997)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266): Caused by:
> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
> Intent { act=android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION
> dat=com.example.fineapp:com.example.fineapp }
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2160)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1736)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5370)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5328)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> com.example.fineapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:25)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8077)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8061)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1315)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3607)
> E/AndroidRuntime(27266):  ... 11 more Error connecting to the service
> protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:50071/ZOmJoxb-uk8=/
> the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I suppose there is an issue with generated URI. There should be scheme as a first parameter (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromParts(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). You may try to run with hardcoded URI first, to check if it works this way.