# start flutter app automatically as phone reboot is done

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I'm using the following [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) in flutter for some background services, it works fine rather the app is closed.
But the background services are killed as the phone gets restarted by its owner.
I want to run my app's background services automatically as soon as the boot is completed.

I tried so many methods on the internet, but nothing seems to be working.
I implemented this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715839/autostart-on-boot-completed-for-flutter-application-based-on-android-example-not) as well, but it's not working and there is no error.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: My answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70980729/11445944 worked for me.

Comment: I implemented this already, but nothing happened and the worst thing is that I did not get any errors.
I added the given code in my MainActivity.kt file